# Changing date format in Phpstorm/Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

That question is not about the code produced by the IDE, it is about IDE itself.

Phpstorm/Intellij always shows dates in "Month/DayOfMonth/Year Hour:Minute" format like 4/16/14 11:40 AM

You can check version control view, local history view or changes view. Is it possible to change the Phpstorm/Intellij date format via GUI or some setting file.

Comment: What is your OS? It seems like it could be configured for Unix. See: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/util/src/com/intellij/util/text/DateFormatUtil.java#L312

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: There is no solution. It uses OS format.

Answer (score 16):

For Live Templates, you can specify the desired format as a date() function parameter (see http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html)

For file templates, I can suggest using separate variables for different date fields. For example, ${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY} instead of ${DATE}

as for version controls, date format is not configurable and different for different VCs. There is no way to set the date format to be used everywhere in the IDE - please vote for [IDEA-99114](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99114). In general, it depends on the system locale

see also comments in [IDEABKL-6449](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6449)